# Getting a count of matched numbers in two series

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

My question is for Google Sheets
I am aware of the countif function and know how to count frequency of one value in a series but I am struggling to find frequency of multiple values in two series. I have tried countifs, arrayformula, countif + sum with and without array formulas but unable to succeed.

example
I have below series in E2:N2

31  32  35  45  49  55  57  66  72  75

and below series in O15:AH15

3   7   12  17  23  25  27  31  39  44  45  48  52  56  61  62  66  69  70  79

I want to see how many values matched and put that in cell A1
In the above example, 3 numbers matched so the value in A1 should be 3

I can do it with countif+countif+countif x 10 times but i wanted a very short formula.

Can someone give me some direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(E2:N2)=O15:AH15)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might serve you: [Countifs in Google Sheets with various 'different than' criteria in same row adds +1 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046939/countifs-in-google-sheets-with-various-different-than-criteria-in-same-row-add)

Basically is how to count based on criteria. there are even 2 sheets for you to check there and copy, you just need to change the criteria of words for the numbers you want to match and count.